# Assertion sv_count !=0 failed - Function train_auto, SVM type - EPS_SVR

Tags: c++, opencv, regression, svm

The question is related to the OpenCV library, version 2.4.13.2.

I am using n dimensional feature vectors from images for training and performing regression. The output values range between 0 and 255. 
The function `CvSVM::train` works without an error, but requires a manual setting of parameters. So, I would prefer using the function `CvSVM::train_auto` to perform cross validation and determine the best parameters for the situation.

But I am facing the error:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (sv_count != 0) in CvSVM::do_train.

On changing the type to `NU_SVR`, it works well. The problem is only with type `EPS_SVR`.

I would appreciate any help I could receive to fix this.

EDIT: I was able to pinpoint the problem to line Number 1786 in the file-

opencv-master\sources\modules\ml\src\svm.cpp

FOR_IN_GRID(p, p_grid)

Upon commenting it, the code runs without errors. I am unaware of the reasons possible.

Comment: Having the same issue here with EPS_SVR

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same bug. Found out that this bug was caused by `svm.setP(x)` and `svm.setTermCriteria((cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS, y))` where x and y values more than 0.1 (10^-1).